# SQL Connection Limit and managing Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, garbage-collection

So, I manage a fairly large web application and I set up a unique method of handling my Entity Framework data context to help with caching across the different events on the page.  From what I had seen before there were basically 2 methods for managing your context across pages in entity framework:

- Create a static context that is shared for all connections.
- Use the connection as disposable within your events.

Because our data changes too rapidly for me to want to use a static context I initially started with disposable connections within each event.  This became problematic since our pages are fairly robust and led to a lot of overhead from constantly opening and closing contexts.  Also, this limited the amount of caching that I could do within the page since I would have to bring the data in fresh for every event.  Finally I decided to go with something new that I had never seen done which is to open one context for each request and hold it open for the entire request.  This gave the best flexibility between both methods and the code is included below:

```
public class FrontEndPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{


    private PageContext _context;
    public Database.DatabaseEntities context
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_context == null)
                _context = new PageContext();
            return _context.Context;
        }
    }
}

public class PageContext
{

    public Database.DatabaseEntities Context;
    public PageContext()
    {
        Context = Database.DatabaseEntities();
    }
}
```

This led to a new and interesting problem.  I started getting an intermittent error connecting to the database.  Once I refresh the application pool, it goes away.  The only thing I could find to explain this is that the entity connection from my method of handling the db context is not always disposing correctly and is ultimately leaving open connections when Garbage Collection fails to clear them out.  After about a day of this it uses up the connection limit for the Sql Server and results in the following error.

```
Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server
Server Error in '/' Application.
Access is denied
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web equest. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Since then I've update the schedule for recycling the application pool down to 4 hour increments, but this is not really a permanent solution.  Because of the way I cache, I definitely want to find a way to make this method of 1 context per request work because it is perfect for the application, but I need a means to make sure that any open contexts are closed correctly.

Is there a better way to handle this or a means of making sure that this connection is closed after the request is completed that I could use to prevent it from leaving the connections hanging?

Or is the error probably being caused by something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to figure out the best solution to this.  I added a page unload event to the custom Page Class that checks if there is an open context and closes the connection  out.  At this point that makes this the best method I've found of handling the connection because it offers the greatest balance of holding your cache and making sure that your objects are always up to date.

```
protected void Page_Unload(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_context != null)
    {
        if (_context.Context.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            _context.Context.Connection.Close();
        _context.Context.Dispose();
        _context.Context = null;
        _context = null;
    }
}
```